# SetGenesis Hex String - Cryptovalues

Tags: bitcoin, nbitcoin

how can I get this hex string from the Dash?

```
SetGenesis ("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")
```

Example:

```
part "57697265642030392f4a616e2f3230313420546865204772616e64204578706572696d656e7420476f6573204c6976653a204f76657273746f636b2e636f6d204973204e6f7720416363657074696e6720426974636f696e73"
```

correspond to

```
"Wired 09/Jan/2014 The Grand Experiment Goes Live: Overstock.com Is Now Accepting Bitcoins"...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Copy in Linux Bitcoin or AltCoins file.dat:"**blk00000.dat**"
- Enter in the folder

```
hexdump -C -s 8 -n 285 blk00000.dat | cut -c 11-58 | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -d ' '
```

Result Example:

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"